# Change countries[ ] to ArrayList<<Post>> android

Tags: android

In my application i am trying to populate a wheel adapter using setter and getter method as shown in my Post Class.

class Post {

```
   private String imageList;
   private String country_name;
   private String country_code;

  public void setImageList (    String imageList){
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }

  public String getImageList (){
        return imageList;
    }


 public void setCountryName (   String country_name){
        this.country_name = country_name;
    }

  public String getCountryName (){
        return country_name;
    }
...


}
```

My wheelAdapter class is as follows:

```
public class SecondWheelAdapter extends AbstractWheelTextAdapter {

    ArrayList<convertor_pst> PostList = new ArrayList<convertor_pst>();

    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    // Countries names
    private String countries[] =
            new String[] {"EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD"};

    // Countries flags
    private int flags[] = new int[] {R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd,R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.usd};

    /**
     * Constructor
     */


    Convertor main;

    public SecondWheelAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.country_layout, NO_RESOURCE);
        setItemTextResource(R.id.country_name);
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        img.setImageResource(flags[index]);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return countries.length;
    }


    @Override
    protected CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        return countries[index];
    }
```

I am trying to replace this array

```
// Countries names
        private String countries[] =
                new String[] {"EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD","EUR", "USD"};
```

with values stored in ArrayList<> but i don't know how to modify countries[] so that it accepts data from my PostList.get(id).getCountryName(); and next i need to set It in              setItemTextResource(R.id.country_name);

Please give me a hint or a tutorial to follow. I get this wheel adapter from github it comes with a library but i am having dificulty.

Answer (score 0):

### Optimized solution:

Instead of managing different String Arrays or ArrayList, I would suggest you to create one ArrayList, it would be easy to manage single ArrayList.

I mean to say remove `countries[]` and `flags[]` and create Single `ArrayList<Post>` type.

Comment: can you provide me an example please

Comment: @yakusha you can do it dear. Simply create one by one 'Post' objects and put it in ArrayList and that's it.

Comment: @yakusha still you can refer [this example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-5-optimized-custom-listview/)

Comment: Implicit super constructor AbstractWheelTextAdapter() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor